# How to obtain solely issues from GitHub's API

Tags: github, github-api

GitHub has the following API to obtain the "issues" from a repository:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues
```

Ok, good right? If you look carefully you'll notice this section:

```
"pull_request": {
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/pulls/76",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/pull/76",
  "diff_url": "https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/pull/76.diff",
  "patch_url": "https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/pull/76.patch"
}
```

this means it's a pull request.

I have done additional testing and it appears that Pull Requests are returned with this API call.

---

I understand GitHub internally considers both Issues and Pull Requests as one of the same, but is there anyway to get *only*, Issues (excluding Pull Requests)?

I **know** I can filter issues on the client side. However if a repository has a much higher ratio of Pull Requests compared to issues, I don't want to make a ridiculous amount of API requests, to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/)

In fact, the point of the GraphQL API is to only specify exactly what you want.

So you can have a query like this:

```
{
  repository(owner: ":owner", name: ":repo") {
    id
    issues(first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          number
          title
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That will return the first 100 issues for a specific repository, and only include the `id`, `number`, `title`, and `url` for each issue.

Useful links:
Repository documentation: https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/object/repository/

Issue documentation: https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/object/issue/

Comment: this helped me a lot, ty wil

Comment: @WillhelmKlopp Does it exclude PRs from the response? I don't think so.